# Fetch detailed Metrics data of non-Spring Java application

Tags: java, prometheus, jmx, talend, jmx-exporter

I am using **JMX Server**, to fetch Metrics data of my application running at Karaf container.

JMX exporter server used: https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter

I *tried with Sample Spring application*, using Micrometer dependency, the Metric logs were very detailed, bearing data about the number of requests, etc data.

But, my target application is not based on Spring. [It runs on **Talend**]

The logs I received over this, do not show any data about the number of REST requests received by the application.

**What additional/alternative should I do, to fetch more details, like Number of requests, etc ?**

---

Metrics logs received for my application:

```
# HELP jmx_config_reload_success_total Number of times configuration have successfully been reloaded.
# TYPE jmx_config_reload_success_total counter
jmx_config_reload_success_total 0.0
# HELP jmx_config_reload_failure_total Number of times configuration have failed to be reloaded.
# TYPE jmx_config_reload_failure_total counter
jmx_config_reload_failure_total 0.0
# HELP jmx_exporter_build_info A metric with a constant '1' value labeled with the version of the JMX exporter.
# TYPE jmx_exporter_build_info gauge
jmx_exporter_build_info{version="0.12.1-SNAPSHOT",name="jmx_prometheus_httpserver",} 1.0
# HELP org_ops4j_pax_web_service_jetty_internal_jettyserverwrapper_stopTimeout The stop timeout in milliseconds (org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal<type=jettyserverwrapper, id=0><>stopTimeout)
# TYPE org_ops4j_pax_web_service_jetty_internal_jettyserverwrapper_stopTimeout untyped
org_ops4j_pax_web_service_jetty_internal_jettyserverwrapper_stopTimeout{id="0",} 30000.0
# HELP org_apache_karaf_instance_Instances_SSH_Port This type describes Karaf instance (org.apache.karaf<type=instance, name=trun, Name=trun><Instances>SSH Port)
# TYPE org_apache_karaf_instance_Instances_SSH_Port untyped
org_apache_karaf_instance_Instances_SSH_Port{name="trun",Name="trun",} 8101.0
# HELP jmx4perl_Config_Debug Attribute exposed for management (jmx4perl<type=Config><>Debug)
# TYPE jmx4perl_Config_Debug untyped
jmx4perl_Config_Debug 0.0
# HELP org_eclipse_jetty_server_session_hashsessionidmanager_stopTimeout The stop timeout in milliseconds (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session<type=hashsessionidmanager, id=0><>stopTimeout)
# TYPE org_eclipse_jetty_server_session_hashsessionidmanager_stopTimeout untyped
org_eclipse_jetty_server_session_hashsessionidmanager_stopTimeout{id="0",} 30000.0
# HELP org_eclipse_jetty_server_SSL_HTTP_1_1_4ef474b6_outputAggregationSize The maximum size in bytes for HTTP output to be aggregated (org.eclipse.jetty.server<context=SSL|HTTP/1.1@4ef474b6, type=httpconfiguration, id=0><>outputAggregationSize)
# TYPE org_eclipse_jetty_server_SSL_HTTP_1_1_4ef474b6_outputAggregationSize untyped
org_eclipse_jetty_server_SSL_HTTP_1_1_4ef474b6_outputAggregationSize{type="httpconfiguration",id="0",} 8192.0
# HELP java_lang_Threading_ThreadContentionMonitoringSupported ThreadContentionMonitoringSupported (java.lang<type=Threading><>ThreadContentionMonitoringSupported)
# TYPE java_lang_Threading_ThreadContentionMonitoringSupported untyped
java_lang_Threading_ThreadContentionMonitoringSupported 1.0
# HELP org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_outputAggregationSize The maximum size in bytes for HTTP output to be aggregated (org.eclipse.jetty.server<context=HTTP/1.1@15470990, type=httpconfiguration, id=0><>outputAggregationSize)
# TYPE org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_outputAggregationSize untyped
org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_outputAggregationSize{type="httpconfiguration",id="0",} 8192.0
# HELP java_lang_Runtime_StartTime StartTime (java.lang<type=Runtime><>StartTime)
# TYPE java_lang_Runtime_StartTime untyped
java_lang_Runtime_StartTime 1.586172506622E12
# HELP org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_137f82d0_acceptQueueSize Accept Queue size (org.eclipse.jetty.server<context=HTTP/1.1@137f82d0, type=serverconnector, id=0><>acceptQueueSize)
# TYPE org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_137f82d0_acceptQueueSize untyped
org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_137f82d0_acceptQueueSize{type="serverconnector",id="0",} 0.0
# HELP org_eclipse_jetty_io_HTTP_1_1_15470990_stopTimeout The stop timeout in milliseconds (org.eclipse.jetty.io<context=HTTP/1.1@15470990, type=managedselector, id=0><>stopTimeout)
# TYPE org_eclipse_jetty_io_HTTP_1_1_15470990_stopTimeout untyped
org_eclipse_jetty_io_HTTP_1_1_15470990_stopTimeout{type="managedselector",id="0",} 30000.0
org_eclipse_jetty_io_HTTP_1_1_15470990_stopTimeout{type="managedselector",id="1",} 30000.0
org_eclipse_jetty_io_HTTP_1_1_15470990_stopTimeout{type="managedselector",id="3",} 30000.0
org_eclipse_jetty_io_HTTP_1_1_15470990_stopTimeout{type="managedselector",id="2",} 30000.0
# HELP java_lang_MemoryPool_UsageThreshold UsageThreshold (java.lang<type=MemoryPool, name=Code Cache><>UsageThreshold)
# TYPE java_lang_MemoryPool_UsageThreshold untyped
java_lang_MemoryPool_UsageThreshold{name="Code Cache",} 0.0
java_lang_MemoryPool_UsageThreshold{name="PS Old Gen",} 0.0
java_lang_MemoryPool_UsageThreshold{name="Compressed Class Space",} 0.0
java_lang_MemoryPool_UsageThreshold{name="Metaspace",} 0.0
# HELP java_lang_Threading_PeakThreadCount PeakThreadCount (java.lang<type=Threading><>PeakThreadCount)
# TYPE java_lang_Threading_PeakThreadCount untyped
java_lang_Threading_PeakThreadCount 109.0
# HELP org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_sendServerVersion Whether to send the Server header in responses (org.eclipse.jetty.server<context=HTTP/1.1@15470990, type=httpconfiguration, id=0><>sendServerVersion)
# TYPE org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_sendServerVersion untyped
org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_sendServerVersion{type="httpconfiguration",id="0",} 1.0
# HELP java_lang_ClassLoading_TotalLoadedClassCount TotalLoadedClassCount (java.lang<type=ClassLoading><>TotalLoadedClassCount)
# TYPE java_lang_ClassLoading_TotalLoadedClassCount untyped
java_lang_ClassLoading_TotalLoadedClassCount 14393.0
# HELP org_eclipse_jetty_server_SSL_HTTP_1_1_4ef474b6_blockingTimeout Total timeout in ms for blocking I/O operations. (org.eclipse.jetty.server<context=SSL|HTTP/1.1@4ef474b6, type=httpconfiguration, id=0><>blockingTimeout)
# TYPE org_eclipse_jetty_server_SSL_HTTP_1_1_4ef474b6_blockingTimeout untyped
org_eclipse_jetty_server_SSL_HTTP_1_1_4ef474b6_blockingTimeout{type="httpconfiguration",id="0",} -1.0
# HELP org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_blockingTimeout Total timeout in ms for blocking I/O operations. (org.eclipse.jetty.server<context=HTTP/1.1@15470990, type=httpconfiguration, id=0><>blockingTimeout)
# TYPE org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_blockingTimeout untyped
org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_blockingTimeout{type="httpconfiguration",id="0",} -1.0
# HELP org_apache_karaf_instance_Instances_Pid This type describes Karaf instance (org.apache.karaf<type=instance, name=trun, Name=trun><Instances>Pid)
# TYPE org_apache_karaf_instance_Instances_Pid untyped
org_apache_karaf_instance_Instances_Pid{name="trun",Name="trun",} 2600.0
# HELP org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_137f82d0_acceptorPriorityDelta The priority delta to apply to acceptor threads (org.eclipse.jetty.server<context=HTTP/1.1@137f82d0, type=serverconnector, id=0><>acceptorPriorityDelta)
# TYPE org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_137f82d0_acceptorPriorityDelta untyped
org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_137f82d0_acceptorPriorityDelta{type="serverconnector",id="0",} -2.0
# HELP org_ops4j_pax_web_service_jetty_internal_jettyserverwrapper_dumpBeforeStop dump state to stderr before stop (org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal<type=jettyserverwrapper, id=0><>dumpBeforeStop)
# TYPE org_ops4j_pax_web_service_jetty_internal_jettyserverwrapper_dumpBeforeStop untyped
org_ops4j_pax_web_service_jetty_internal_jettyserverwrapper_dumpBeforeStop{id="0",} 0.0
# HELP org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_requestHeaderSize The maximum allowed size in bytes for a HTTP request header (org.eclipse.jetty.server<context=HTTP/1.1@15470990, type=httpconfiguration, id=0><>requestHeaderSize)
# TYPE org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_requestHeaderSize untyped
org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_requestHeaderSize{type="httpconfiguration",id="0",} 8192.0
# HELP org_apache_cxf_Shared_WorkQueueMaxSize The WorkQueueMaxSize (org.apache.cxf<bus.id=Shared, type=WorkQueues, name=default, instance.id=131247914><>WorkQueueMaxSize)
# TYPE org_apache_cxf_Shared_WorkQueueMaxSize untyped
org_apache_cxf_Shared_WorkQueueMaxSize{type="WorkQueues",name="default",instance_id="131247914",} 50.0
# HELP java_lang_MemoryPool_PeakUsage_committed java.lang.management.MemoryUsage (java.lang<type=MemoryPool, name=Code Cache><PeakUsage>committed)
# TYPE java_lang_MemoryPool_PeakUsage_committed untyped
java_lang_MemoryPool_PeakUsage_committed{name="Code Cache",} 2.3003136E7
java_lang_MemoryPool_PeakUsage_committed{name="PS Old Gen",} 2.7000832E8
java_lang_MemoryPool_PeakUsage_committed{name="Compressed Class Space",} 1.245184E7
java_lang_MemoryPool_PeakUsage_committed{name="Metaspace",} 8.7031808E7
java_lang_MemoryPool_PeakUsage_committed{name="PS Eden Space",} 2.92028416E8
java_lang_MemoryPool_PeakUsage_committed{name="PS Survivor Space",} 2.3068672E7
# HELP org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_acceptors number of acceptor threads (org.eclipse.jetty.server<context=HTTP/1.1@15470990, type=serverconnector, id=0><>acceptors)
# TYPE org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_acceptors untyped
org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_15470990_acceptors{type="serverconnector",id="0",} 1.0
# HELP org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_137f82d0_delayDispatchUntilContent Whether to delay the application dispatch until content is available (org.eclipse.jetty.server<context=HTTP/1.1@137f82d0, type=httpconfiguration, id=0><>delayDispatchUntilContent)
# TYPE org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_137f82d0_delayDispatchUntilContent untyped
org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_137f82d0_delayDispatchUntilContent{type="httpconfiguration",id="0",} 1.0
# HELP org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay Blueprint event (org.apache.aries.blueprint<service=blueprintState, version=1.0, BundleId=192><LastEvents>Replay)
# TYPE org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay untyped
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="192",} 0.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="98",} 1.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="194",} 0.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="198",} 0.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="199",} 0.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="201",} 0.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="204",} 0.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="12",} 0.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="205",} 0.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="46",} 0.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="112",} 1.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="241",} 0.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="246",} 0.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="248",} 0.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="25",} 1.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="26",} 1.0
org_apache_aries_blueprint_blueprintState_LastEvents_Replay{version="1.0",BundleId="221",} 1.0
# HELP java_nio_BufferPool_Count Count (java.nio<type=BufferPool, name=direct><>Count)
# TYPE java_nio_BufferPool_Count untyped
java_nio_BufferPool_Count{name="direct",} 5.0
java_nio_BufferPool_Count{name="mapped",} 0.0
# HELP java_lang_Threading_ThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled ThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled (java.lang<type=Threading><>ThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled)
# TYPE java_lang_Threading_ThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled untyped
java_lang_Threading_ThreadAllocatedMemoryEnabled 1.0
# HELP jolokia_Config_HistoryMaxEntries Attribute exposed for management (jolokia<type=Config><>HistoryMaxEntries)
# TYPE jolokia_Config_HistoryMaxEntries untyped
jolokia_Config_HistoryMaxEntries 10.0
# HELP java_lang_OperatingSystem_ProcessCpuLoad ProcessCpuLoad (java.lang<type=OperatingSystem><>ProcessCpuLoad)
# TYPE java_lang_OperatingSystem_ProcessCpuLoad untyped
java_lang_OperatingSystem_ProcessCpuLoad 0.12238162074777716
# HELP org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_137f82d0_localPort local port (org.eclipse.jetty.server<context=HTTP/1.1@137f82d0, type=serverconnector, id=0><>localPort)
# TYPE org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_137f82d0_localPort untyped
org_eclipse_jetty_server_HTTP_1_1_137f82d0_localPort{type="serverconnector",id="0",} 8040.0

org_apache_cxf_Shared_LowWaterMark{type="WorkQueues",name="default",instance_id="131247914",} 5.0
# HELP jmx_scrape_duration_seconds Time this JMX scrape took, in seconds.
# TYPE jmx_scrape_duration_seconds gauge
jmx_scrape_duration_seconds 7.527235
# HELP jmx_scrape_error Non-zero if this scrape failed.
# TYPE jmx_scrape_error gauge
jmx_scrape_error 0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apache CXF** library provided me these data.

attaching screenshot of `jconsole` for same, where I am getting count for number of REST hits.

Data collected after 5 HTTP POST requests.

[image]